# Typedef a Vector Iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, typedef

Whenever I do

`typedef std::vector< SomeType >::iterator`

I get the error:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 5)
```

Why is this? Is it possible to typedef a c++ vector or a vector iterator?

Comment: You need to then give the replacement a name, like `typedef current-name new-alias`.

Comment: Sorry! Lack of sleep has led to some idiotic maneuvers on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works fine:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
typedef string_vector::iterator str_vect_itr;
```

I would look at your typedefs carefully...